# How to setup Cron (Media Temple Dedicated Virtual/Parallels)

Tags: cron, mediatemple

I am learning how to use Cron jobs. The server I am working on is [Media Temple Dedicated Virtual Server](http://mediatemple.net/webhosting/dv/). The "Control Panel" is [Parallels](http://www.parallels.com/products/plesk/). I cant find where I can setup cron jobs.

Is SSH the only way? Since I am unfamiliar, anyone care to give me some pointers to learn it abit?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest contacting their customer support or looking into the Knowledge Base. Both are excellent at Media Temple.

For example:

http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/82/Using+Cron+on+a+%28dv%29+Dedicated+Virtual+Server

:-)

Comment: I saw that article but I dont see cron/scheduled task on my control panel which looks like http://imgur.com/Sfs2w.jpg or http://imgur.com/lg2te.jpg

Answer (score 0):

On this screenshot from the Media Temple website you can see "scheduled tasks" http://s3.mt-cdn.net/_images/screenshots/plesk_serveradmin__84a459d.jpg. That's probably the place to start. (I guess they call it that because cron is too technical.)

Comment: my control panel looks different like [this](http://imgur.com/Sfs2w.jpg) & [this](http://imgur.com/lg2te.jpg). with no scheduled tasks or cron ... perhaps it a different version

Answer (score 0):

Review this (mt) Wiki article: http://wiki.mediatemple.net/w/%28dv%29:Cron

If you're on a (dv) 4.0, in Plesk you'll navigate to Tools & Utilities, then Scheduled Tasks. If you need more assistance, I recommend reaching out to the (mt) forums.